# FFMPEG via PHP - no thumbnail or log output generated

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get my head around command line syntax in the form of FFMPEG via PHP.

I've successfully installed it and I can use it fine, until I try to:

- run background tasks
- generate output to a log

This code attempts to create a thumbnail from a video. And it does, if I make it synchrnous, i.e. remove everything from onwards `</dev`....

```
shell_exec($i = 'ffmpeg -y -i '.$fp.' -ss '.$secs.' -vframes 1 '.$dirs_path.'/thumb.png  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/ffmpeg.txt &');
```

I've derived the background part of this command from [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) on the official FFMPEG site.

(`$secs` is an integer denoting a seconds point within the video duration, and `$fp` is the save path of the video. Both are valid.)

So the thumb doesn't get generated, and there's no ffmpeg.txt created, either in the place where the script runs, or in the server root or anything. I may be looking in the wrong place... I'm unsure what all this is relative to.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have write access to `/`? because is trying to write `ffmpeg.txt` inside `/`

Comment: Ah, that's what I was unsure of, what the write industruction was relative to. So should I put something like `/home/username/public_html/`?

Comment: You can use relative paths but the file will probably be relative to the path where PHP runs.
So it may be better to use absolute paths in both the `ffmpeg.txt` and your `thumb.png`
also the `ffmpeg.txt` file is only created when there are errors, if you want to see the output for any execution you can change it like
`shell_exec($i = 'ffmpeg -y -i '.$fp.' -ss '.$secs.' -vframes 1 '.$dirs_path.'/thumb.png >/opt/ffmpeg.txt 2&1 </dev/null &');`
in that way the `ffmpeg.txt` will be saved in `opt`

Comment: Thanks. How about the question re: thumb not being created when I set it to run as a background task? It DOES create the thumb if I make it run immediately - same paths, no change, everything good.

Comment: Add `-report` to your ffmpeg command then look for a (very verbose) log named something like `ffmpeg-20181010-100310.log`. If the log exists then ffmpeg was executed. View log for errors (near end of file).

Comment: Thanks, @LordNeckbeard. Would I expect to find this file in the server root, same folder as script execution, etc, ?

Comment: In the current directory of `ffmpeg` execution.

Comment: Check this issue http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#118495 if that is the case then the problem is the redirection to the file, if you don't need the output from ffpmeg, just use

`shell_exec($i = 'ffmpeg -y -i '.$fp.' -ss '.$secs.' -vframes 1 '.$dirs_path.'/thumb.png >/dev/null 2&1 </dev/null &');`

or if you need the output go with the option with `tee` command